# File not found error in C#

Tags: c#

I have some interesting error in C# while reading a TXT file after a process ran. This process run some operations and after it finishes, copy its output to a TXT file. This txt file shown below as output.txt.

When I'm trying to run it it throws an error called file not found. But if I try to debug it with pressing F10 file can be found and everything works fine.

I guess that problem occurs when code runs while process working in the background. Code requires txt file but process still working. And error thrown.

Here its my code.

```
var aprioriProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
aprioriProcess.UseShellExecute = true;

string supportValue = T_minSupport.Text;
string workingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string outputFile = "output.txt";

int index = workingDirectory.IndexOf("bin");

if (index > 0)
{
    workingDirectory = workingDirectory.Remove(index, 10);
}

if (File.Exists(workingDirectory + "/output.txt"))
{
    File.Delete(workingDirectory + "/output.txt");
}

//proc1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\berki\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DataMining\DataMining";
aprioriProcess.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
aprioriProcess.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";

string command = "-s" + supportValue + " census.dat - >> " + outputFile;
aprioriProcess.Arguments = "/c apriori.exe " + command;

Process.Start(aprioriProcess);

string fileName = outputFile;
fileReader.ReadFile(workingDirectory + fileName);
aprioriLines = fileReader.GetEntries().Cast<AprioriOutput>().ToList();
```

Maybe not deleting it but updating that txt file will solve my problem but im not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Is the path proper then? Print out the workingDirectory and check.

Comment: First, replace `"/output.txt"` with `"\output.txt"`, and then don't you need to change `workingDirectory + fileName` to `workingDirectory + "\" + fileName`?

Comment: Yes path is true. Its not about path. I checked it already. Thanks by the way

Comment: Also, consider changeing `workingDirectory` to `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. If you still had problem, give us the value of he `workingDirectory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re not waiting for the process to end, as I think you have realised. You need to store the result from `Process.Start` and wait for it to exit:

```
var process = Process.Start(aprioriProcess);

process.WaitForExit();
```

For further info, check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, i found this solution on the web and checked here BOOM. You have already written. Thanks alot. This method works fine

Comment: @Berkin — Don't forget to mark this as the answer. Q&A is the lifeblood of SO.

Comment: Yes of course i'm going to mark it. Stackoverflow made that tick disabled for 10 minutes after question asked. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Start() method starts the process, but doesn't wait for finish. So the file is -probably- not ready at the ReadFile() line.

```
Process p = Process.Start(aprioriProcess);
p.WaitForExit();
```